# Frame rate in Premiere Pro CS5.5 problem

Tags: premiere, framerate

This is a unique situation. I started a new job and they have me using an old version of Premiere I'm not familiar with (5.5).

I have an mp4 that is 48.93 fps. It plays back fine in video players on the PC. But as soon as I import it into Premiere, the playback changes. The video is fast-forward but the audio is normal.

It doesn't matter what the sequence setting is, it still plays back with the video on FF. I tried rendering it and the rendered version is also FF (but again, audio is normal).

Any ideas?
Thanks